# How to set a name of grouping variable column when wrapping data table into function

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, user-defined-functions, custom-function

I would like to be able to change a name of column which contains the grouping variable in the data table. I know how to do this when not wrapping into a function, but when I wrap the group by data table operation into a function, I am unable to figure out how to also set the name to truly reflect the grouping variable.

My code:

```
# load the data table library
library(data.table)
# load sample dataset for reproducible example
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
# define a function which would group given
# data table (1st parameter) by given column (2nd parameter)
grouping_function <- function(x, grouping1)
{
  x[,
    list(mean_disp = mean(disp),
           mean_hp = mean(hp)),
    .(get(grouping1))]
}
```

Now, if I run `grouping_function(mtcars, "cyl")` I would like to get column names **cyl, mean_disp, mean_hp** byt what I get is **get, mean_disp, mean_hp**

**EDIT**

For one variable the fix seems to be strightforward as suggested by the answer of Roman Lustrik. But when I have two grouping variables, that fix doesn't seem to work:

```
# load the data table library
library(data.table)
# load sample dataset for reproducible example
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
# define a function which would group given
# data table (1st parameter) by given column (2nd parameter)
grouping_function <- function(x, grouping1, grouping2)
{
  x[,
    list(mean_disp = mean(disp),
           mean_hp = mean(hp)),
    .(get(grouping1), get(grouping2)]
}
```

Here, using merely by = list(grouping1, grouping2) or other variants seem to fail.

Comment: Normally, when you read data from your notepad, you can load the column names by adding 'T' at the end of the data address separately by a comma. But this looks like your are not using read command but rather loading the pre-set data in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just specify `by`?

```
grouping_function <- function(x, grouping1) {
  x[,
    list(mean_disp = mean(disp),
         mean_hp = mean(hp)),
    by = grouping1]
}

grouping_function(mtcars, "cyl")

   cyl mean_disp   mean_hp
1:   6  183.3143 122.28571
2:   4  105.1364  82.63636
3:   8  353.1000 209.21429
```

Comment: Hmm... seems I chose a bit bad example. Can you please also advise how to do this in case of two grouping variables?

Comment: Wow, if I read the vignette carefully I would have found out that by parameter uses character vector instead of a list. Problem solved, thank you!